# Which blackberry for testing?

Tags: blackberry, mobile

I have a t-mobile pre-paid sim and wifi. I'm working on a website that would like to target BB 6 and newer. One of the unique things about the BB is that many of the devices have a keyboard and touchpad.

Is there a device with a keyboard I can get that would work with my sim and wifi that would let me test websites? (without a data plan)

I looked at the BB Bold 9900. This seems to be the right type of device but that particular model is a bit pricey. Would be nice to go back a generation.

Just to be clear, my requirements are:

- Work without a data plan (therefore wifi)
- Keyboard / touchpad (touch screen optional but nice)
- Compatible with t-mobile prepaid sim.
- BlackBerry OS 6

I'd love to hear your suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BB 9700](http://us.blackberry.com/support/devices/blackberrybold9700.jsp) - while launched with OS5, can meanwhile run OS6 too. No touch screen though

[image]

Comment: Thanks, found one locally, picking it up tonight.

Comment: I ended up with the Bold 9650, a CDMA "World Phone" branded for US Cellular. It came with OS 6. Without a sim it picked up my wifi and browsed the web just fine. I popped in my t-mobile sim and fiddled with a few settings telling it to prefer GSM/UTMS over CDMA and it hopped onto t-mobile just fine. I have to say, this is a very high quality user experience. It's not touch screen, so hard to compare to the iPhone, but a solid device none the less.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just get the cheapest one. Not sure you need your SIM to work in it if you're just using WiFi.

FYI, you can download blackberry simulators from RIM. They're not quite the same as using the actual device (namely in terms of keyboard simulation) but they work in a pinch.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't trying the 9930 Blackberry device running OS 7.0
It will meet all your requirements